# python TypeError : unbound method UpdateVideoEntry() must be called with YouTubeService instance

Tags: python, youtube

I'm trying to update an entry using the youtube api.  Here is my error i'm struggling with:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       updated_entry = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService.UpdateVideoEntry(YTVentry.id)
>   TypeError: unbound method UpdateVideoEntry() must be called with
>   YouTubeService instance as first argument (got NoneType instance
>   instead)

Here is my code:

```
    import gdata.youtube
    import gdata.youtube.service
    import gdata.youtube.data
client = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()    
...
videos_feed = client.GetYouTubeVideoFeed(uri)
    for entry in videos_feed.entry:
    print entry.title.text
        YTentry = entry._GDataEntry__GetId
        YTVentry = gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoEntry(YTentry)
        YTVentry.media.title = '09.11.2012 Hold me close'
        YTVentry.media.description = '09.11.2012 : Hold me close section'
        updated_entry = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService.UpdateVideoEntry(YTVentry.id)
```

According to the google gdata youtube docs:

> To update video meta-data, simply update the YouTubeVideoEntry object
>   and then use the YouTubeService objects' UpdateVideoEntry method. This
>   method takes as a parameter a YouTubeVideoEntry that contains updated
>   meta-data.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
    updated_entry = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService.UpdateVideoEntry(YTVentry.id)
```

should be

```
    updated_entry = client.UpdateVideoEntry(YTVentry.id)
```

> gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService.UpdateVideoEntry(YTVentry.id)
>   TypeError: unbound method UpdateVideoEntry() must be called with
>   YouTubeService instance as first argument (got NoneType instance
>   instead)

The error is complaining because you are trying to call UpdateVideoEntry from the class rather then the client object you created. You've created a YouTubeService object, `client` and you need to use that rather then calling the classes' method directy.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the method on the `YouTubeService` class, not on an instance of that class. In other words, you should be calling `client.UpdateVideoEntry(...)` instead of `YouTubeService.UpdateVideoEntry(...)` as with your other calls to the API.

The documentation even says you should call the method on a `YouTubeService` object, not on the class.

The error message indicates that you *can* call the class method directly, but you must pass an instance of the class as the first parameter. This is done implicitly when you call the method on an instance, but must be done explicitly when calling the method on the class. Otherwise Python won't know what instance the method should operate on (i.e., what `self` is).